# Cannot find MessageSource Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to validate a form and load messages from a properties file `"ErrorMessages.properties"` .The properties file is places as shown in image

[image: Project Structure]

I have places following code in my dispatcher servlet

```
<!-- Register the properties files -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:ErrorMessages.properties" />
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

The projects gets deployed but i cant see error messages. I get following warning

```
WARNING: ResourceBundle [classpath:ErrorMessages.properties] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name classpath:ErrorMessages.properties, locale en_GB
```

And yeah i do have another property loader

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:conf.properties" />
```

I am new to spring and its been a while i am trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your bundles in the standard location:

```
 src/main/resources
```

If you follow this convention, your `messageSource` bean should be defined like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="message" />
</bean>
```

With `message_en_GB.properties` in the same folder as your `spring.xml`.

Comment: Provided he has a maven project, but from the screenshot and description I can't tell if it's so